# Use JQuery to access items from $.GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post, http-get

Like my title says, is it possible to use JQuery to access elements found in a return "data" object from $GET or $POST?

```
    $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    });
```

Let's say the data from $.GET is this:

```
<h1>hey world</h1>
<p id='first'>first item</p>
```

Could I access the info with something like this?

```
var item = $(data).('#first').html();
```

Comment: `var item = $(data).filter('#first').html();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this *inside* that callback since the call is async, this ensures you have access to the `data` right when it comes back:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    var item = $(data).filter('#first').html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use filter():

```
var item = $(data).filter('#first').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .filter() to filter out the required element from the element collection. Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for more reference.

Try this,

```
var item = $(data).filter('#first').html();
```